# NSProgress resume after calling pause

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa

[NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSProgress) allows work to be cancelled or resumed by the user. You pause an `NSProgress` object by calling `pause` on it.

How do you resume a paused `NSProgress` object? The documentation for `NSProgress` doesn't actually mention resuming. WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resume` has now been added to NSProgress in iOS 9 and OS X 10.11.

```
- (void)resume NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSProgress` is about progress reporting and **allowing** user to cancel.

All that happens in that case is that your `pausingHandler` is called, which should specify:
*The block to invoke when progress is paused.*

**If** you actually pause is up to you.

Comment: Then why *can* you pause an NSProgress object? Would it keep updating its `fractionCompleted` property?